# Change value of a float in a cell

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML table which contains a value as well as a checkbox every row.
When I click on the checkbox, it activates a script which adds this value in another fixed cell. If the checkbox is checked, it adds the number, if it is unchecked, it subtracts the number.

```
function val_sel_achat(val, id)
{
    if (document.getElementById(id).checked)
    {
        document.getElementById('res_achat').innerHTML += val;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('res_achat').innerHTML -= val;
    }
}
```

It's mostly working well, except that it seems to concatenate chains rather than add numbers.
So if I check a box with val = 100, then uncheck it, it displays 100, then 0, which is alright.
But if I check two different boxes, like 100 and 25, it displays 10025.

How would I change my code so it displays 125 instead?

Thanks.

Comment: if you have problem with rounding, use this: `document.getElementById('res_achat').innerHTML = (parseFloat(x) + val).toFixed(2);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function val_sel_achat(val, id)
{
    var x = document.getElementById('res_achat').innerHTML;
    if (document.getElementById(id).checked)
    {
        document.getElementById('res_achat').innerHTML = parseFloat(x) + val;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('res_achat').innerHTML = parseFloat(x) - val;
    }
}
```

Comment: It returns NaN, even if I do a parseFloat(val) instead of val.

Comment: @user2542743 so the contents of res_achat is not just a number? Replace the first line with one that gets the actual number in res_achat

Comment: At first it was empty. I changed it to 0, works like a charm now, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.parseFloat()`

```
function val_sel_achat(val, id) {
    var inner = document.getElementById('res_achat').innerHTML;
    if (document.getElementById(id).checked) {
        document.getElementById('res_achat').innerHTML = parseFloat(inner) + parseFloat(val);
    } else {
        document.getElementById('res_achat').innerHTML = parseFloat(inner) - parseFloat(val);
    }
}
```

A sample working without checkbox [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fUMJe/1/)